# Unable to glean data from other pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using post requests to get data from a webpage. The webpage traverses 57 pages with a next or dropdown button. What I've written so far can fetch data only from the first page. I tried a lot to find a way to capture data going through it's next pages but failed. How can I get data from all of the 57 pages? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

with requests.session() as session:
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    page = session.post("http://registers.centralbank.ie/(X(1)S(cvjcqdbijraticyy2ssdyqav))/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx?searchEntity=FundServiceProvider&searchType=Name&searchText=&registers=6%2c29%2c44%2c45&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1", 
            data={'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages':'2'}, 
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})


    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles = tree.cssselect("table")[1]
    list_row =[[tab_d.text_content() for tab_d in item.cssselect('td.gvwColumn,td.entityNameColumn,td.entityTradingNameColumn')]
                for item in titles.cssselect('tr')]

for data in list_row:
    print(' '.join(data))
```

This is [The Link](http://registers.centralbank.ie/(X(1)S(cvjcqdbijraticyy2ssdyqav))/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx?searchEntity=FundServiceProvider&searchType=Name&searchText=&registers=6%2c29%2c44%2c45&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to that page

Btw, I didn't find any paginated links through which I can go on to the next page except for the "data" in requests parameter where there is a page number option which changes when button is clicked. However, changing that number doesn't bring data from other pages.